# AWS-CDK : CNAMEPrefix is not getting set in the elasticbeanstalk.CfnEnvironment

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cdk

I am trying to deploy a NodeJS app to elastic beanstalk using AWS CDK, things are working fine, deployment and redeployment works fine.However, the final URL which is generated has random string like '*MyDeployEnv1.**eba-5vjzkdss**.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com*'. While reading through various AWS documentation I came across the property [CNAMEPrefix](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-beanstalk-environment.html).
So I added the CNAMEPrefix in the elasticbeanstalk.CfnEnvironment call as below :

```js
const elbEnv = new elasticbeanstalk.CfnEnvironment(this, 'Environment', {
  environmentName: 'MyDeployEnv1',
  CNAMEPrefix: 'myapi14',
  applicationName: app.applicationName || appName,
  solutionStackName: '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v4.17.0 running Node.js',
  optionSettings: optionSettingProperties,
  versionLabel: appVersionProps.ref,
});
```

**CNAMEPrefix** is not working, any help to change/remove the random alphanumeric string in the URL would be helpful '*MyDeployEnv1.**eba-5vjzkdss**.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com*'

**Version details** :
**aws-cli** 2.1.1 Windows/10 exe/AMD64
**CDK version** : 1.75.0 (build 7708242)